# Get Android app Icon by package name from javascript code

Tags: javascript, android, google-play, icons

I'm trying to get application icon from my web javascript code using package name only.

How can I fetch it from google play store?
Is the only way is scraping? Is it dangerous?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this from android webview or in a web browser JS?

Comment: from Java you can access the list of packages on the device. From JS you probably can't. What you can is to fetch it from it's google play page

Comment: edited
@Carrot--Show web browser js

Comment: @VladMatvienko how can I fetch it from google play store?

Comment: as @VladMatvienko said you can only fetch it from Google Play, but:
1) Google Play ToS forbids page crawling
2) You can't do it with pure JS, because CORS Policy.
You may want to use php.

Comment: @Carrot--Show so scraping is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get application icon from Google Play App info page you need just extract them from the correct selectors, but you need an applicaton id. To do this you can search what you want on Google Play main page, get the first result (most relevant to your search) and parse app id from it.

I'll show how you can do this in the code below ([also check it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Play-App-Icon-with-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js)):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const searchQuery = "asphalt 9"; // what you want to search

const mainOptions = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36",
  }, // adding the User-Agent header as one way to prevent the request from being blocked
  hl: "en", // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  gl: "us", // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
};

function getAppId() {
  const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
    headers: mainOptions.headers,
    params: {
      q: searchQuery,
      c: "apps", // parameter defines category of the search. "apps" means apps & games category
      hl: mainOptions.hl,
      gl: mainOptions.gl,
    },
  };
  return axios.get(`https://play.google.com/store/search`, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(function ({ data }) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const link = `https://play.google.com${$('[jscontroller="gKWqec"] .ULeU3b .Si6A0c')?.attr("href")}`;
    const appId = link.slice(link.indexOf("?id=") + 4);

    return appId;
  });
}

function getAppInfo(id) {
  const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
    headers: mainOptions.headers,
    params: {
      id, // Parameter defines the ID of a product you want to get the results for
      hl: mainOptions.hl,
      gl: mainOptions.gl,
    },
  };
  return axios.get(`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details`, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(function ({ data }) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(data);

    return {
      thumbnail: $(".l8YSdd > img")?.attr("srcset")?.slice(0, -3),
    };
  });
}

getAppId().then(getAppInfo).then(console.log);
```

Output

```json
{
  "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/PJo-zZiPokt4vUPri7-md-S-adydt9HPf9yfAcuKift7tYTC1cyrhpxmqFPQbuDRrDU=w240-h480-rw"
}
```

You can read more about scraping Google Play App info from my blog post [Web scraping Google Play App Info with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-google-play-app-info-with-nodejs/).